# Java KeyStore file works well in SOAPUI but not in RestAssured

Tags: web-services, soap, soapui, rest-assured, web-api-testing

I have soap web services for which I have used SOAPUI for manual test run. The SSL is authenticated with jks file (java keystore file).
It works well in SOAPUI, but I am trying to use RestAssured for SOAP testing. I have tried some demo samples and they work (but they are deviod of SSL authentication).
My project (which is a bank) uses jks file for SSL pass through, and it doesn't work when I use it in RestAssured.
I cannot paste the exact code from my project as it is confidential and could not be brought out of the environment, hence pasting a model of what I did.

The errors I get are:

1. I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when connecting to {s}-> https://mybaseuri:1234: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respong after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
2. javax.net.ssl.SSLHandShakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

```
public void acctSumm(){
        String keyStr = "absolute path to keystore file which is located in the project folder itself";
        
        String payload = "soap xml body";
        
        Response response = RestAssured.given()
                .keyStore(keyStr, "passwrd")
                .baseUri("https://mybaseuri:1234")
                .basePath("/accountSummary")
                .header("SOAPAction", "AcctSummaryInq")
                .header("Content-Type", "text/xml;, charset=utf-8")
                .body(payload)
                .post();
                
    }
```

I also tried another approach

```
 public void acctSumm(){
        String keyStr = "absolute path to keystore file which is located in the project folder itself";

        String payload = "soap xml body";
        RestAssured.baseURI = "https://mybaseuri:1234";
        Response response = given()
                .keyStore(keyStr, "passwrd")
                .header("Content-Type", "text/xml")
                .body(payload)
                .when()
                .post("AcctSummaryInq")
                .then()
                .statusCode(200)
                .and()
                .log().all().extract().response();

    }
```

Comment: SoapUI, by default, uses it's own installation of Java (in $SOAPUI_HOME/jre), **different** from the rest of your system. Where and how did you import the .jks?

Comment: @SiKing Thank you for your response. I placed the jks file in the project folder itself.

Comment: Use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7812444/3124333) to import your jks.